# How many degrees of freedom would water have at $\rm 500K$?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, molecules, degrees-of-freedom

At this temperature, and lower, the rotational degrees of freedom would already be in action, then at this higher temperature id think vibration degrees of freedom are no longer frozen out. So this gives us a total of 6 right?

Answer (score 2):

A molecule with $N$ atoms will in general have $3N$ degrees of freedom, i.e., $3$ per every atom (see the table in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(physics_and_chemistry)#Thermodynamic_degrees_of_freedom_for_gases)). Indeed, at low temperatures the vibrational degrees of freedom are *frozen out*, i.e., the motion of the molecule can be considered as the motion of a rigid body with $3$ translational and $3$ rotational degrees of freedom. At higher temperatures each atom can move on its own, although without leaving too far. In terms of the vibrational degrees of freedom this can be seen as:

- contraction/extension of all the bonds
- changing the angle between the bonds.

Thus, a water molecule has 3 atoms, which give $3+3=6$ degrees of freedom at low temperatures, plus two degrees of freedom due to the bond contruction, plus one degree of freedom due to changing of the angle between the two $OH$ bonds.

Comment: 500K is not nearly hot enough to excite the stretch and bending modes significantly. They are at 3450, 3615, and 1640 cycles/cm.  Try 5000 and 2500K.  Liquid water's heat capacity is greater than anything naively predicted by counting degrees of freedom.

Comment: @BertBarrois Yes, I suspected that the specific numbers for vibrational frequencies are too high to be excited at 500K. If you can give a handy reference to the vibration frequency energies, I woudl be glad to add it to the answer.